# Problem on Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI) index calculation on image (R)

Tags: r, image-processing, matrix, raster

I want to calculate the number of pixels having a value higher than a limit (0.02 in the following code) of an image after obtaining one NDVI index (called S in the following code). I tried many way but it does not work (I already check that I have value lower than 0.02). The image used:   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HCuZ.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HCuZ.jpg

```
## load package
library(raster)
library(oceanmap)
#load satellite image of a park
f <- stack(list.files(path='C:/Users/Desktop/Segmentation', full.names=TRUE))
###################################################
###################################################
b <- brick(f)
###################################################
# obtain the R, G and B layer of the initial image raster
R <- b[[1]]
G <- b[[2]]
B <- b[[3]]
###################################################
#color vegetation indices
S <- (G-B)/(R+G+B)
> class(S)
[1] "RasterLayer"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
> SumS0 <- as.numeric(sum(S[] < 0.02))
> SumS0
[1] NA
> S1 <- as.matrix(S)
> SumS1 <- as.numeric(sum(S1[] < 0.02))
> class(S1)
[1] "matrix" "array" 
> SumS1
[1] NA
> S2 <- raster2matrix(S)
> SumS2 <- as.numeric(sum(S2[] < 0.02))
> SumS2
[1] NA
> S3 <- as.data.frame(S)
> SumS3 <- as.numeric(sum(S3[] < 0.02))
> SumS3
[1] NA
```

For a random matrix it works:

```
M1<-matrix(rnorm(36),nrow=6)
SumM1 <- as.numeric(sum(M1[] < 0.02))
SumM1
[1] 15
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `sum(as.numeric(S) < 0.02, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks, it works using sum(S[] < 0.02, na.rm = TRUE)

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm for calculating NDVI seems correct, so I assume there is something wrong with your implementation. If I run that with **ImageMagick**, I get what I would expect:

[image]

I used this in Terminal:

```
magick 8HCuZ.jpg -fx "((g-b)/(r+g+b))>0.02 ? 1 : 0" result.png
```

By the way, the quality of your photo (70) is rather low and leads to ugly artefacts.